# Calcular la ocurrencia de elementos en valores de un diccionario

Tags: python, python-3.x, diccionarios

Intento hacer un count sobre un directorio. Cuando lo convierto en un diccionario, puedo aplicar una fórmula, que aún no entiendo del todo, a decir verdad.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"QID":[1177],"Questions":["The travel restrictions of COVID-19 have been lifted and you are looking to book a flight. To what extent are the following factors considerations in your choice of flight?"],"QType":["Likert Scale"],"Answer0":["Very important consideration"],"Answer1":["Important consideration"],"Answer2":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer3":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer4":["Do not consider"],"Answer5":["Discounted flights"],"Answer6":["Very important consideration"],"Answer7":["Important consideration"],"Answer8":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer9":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer10":["Do not consider"],"Answer11":["Baggage policy"],"Answer12":["Very important consideration"],"Answer13":["Important consideration"],"Answer14":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer15":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer16":["Do not consider"],"Answer17":["Price of flights"],"Answer18":["Very important consideration"],"Answer19":["Important consideration"],"Answer20":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer21":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer22":["Do not consider"],"Answer23":["Insurance"],"Answer24":["Very important consideration"],"Answer25":["Important consideration"],"Answer26":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer27":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer28":["Do not consider"],"Answer29":["Airport services"],"Answer30":["Very important consideration"],"Answer31":["Important consideration"],"Answer32":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer33":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer34":["Do not consider"],"Answer35":["Environmental impact"],"Answer36":["Very important consideration"],"Answer37":["Important consideration"],"Answer38":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer39":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer40":["Do not consider"],"Answer41":["In-flight service"],"Answer42":["Very important consideration"],"Answer43":["Important consideration"],"Answer44":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer45":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer46":["Do not consider"],"Answer47":["Customer support"],"Answer48":["Very important consideration"],"Answer49":["Important consideration"],"Answer50":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer51":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer52":["Do not consider"],"Answer53":["Overcrowding on aircraft/airports"],"Answer54":["Very important consideration"],"Answer55":["Important consideration"],"Answer56":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer57":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer58":["Do not consider"],"Answer59":["Airport safety after COVID-19"],"Answer60":["Very important consideration"],"Answer61":["Important consideration"],"Answer62":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer63":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer64":["Do not consider"],"Answer65":["Refund policy"]})

def gettruc(r):
    print({k:v for k,v in collections.Counter(r[3:].values).items() if v>1})

df = df.apply(lambda r: gettruc(r), axis=1)
```

Pero cuando intento simplemente con el diccionario solo:

```
d = {"QID":[1177],"Questions":["The travel restrictions of COVID-19 have been lifted and you are looking to book a flight. To what extent are the following factors considerations in your choice of flight?"],"QType":["Likert Scale"],"Answer0":["Very important consideration"],"Answer1":["Important consideration"],"Answer2":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer3":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer4":["Do not consider"],"Answer5":["Discounted flights"],"Answer6":["Very important consideration"],"Answer7":["Important consideration"],"Answer8":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer9":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer10":["Do not consider"],"Answer11":["Baggage policy"],"Answer12":["Very important consideration"],"Answer13":["Important consideration"],"Answer14":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer15":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer16":["Do not consider"],"Answer17":["Price of flights"],"Answer18":["Very important consideration"],"Answer19":["Important consideration"],"Answer20":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer21":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer22":["Do not consider"],"Answer23":["Insurance"],"Answer24":["Very important consideration"],"Answer25":["Important consideration"],"Answer26":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer27":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer28":["Do not consider"],"Answer29":["Airport services"],"Answer30":["Very important consideration"],"Answer31":["Important consideration"],"Answer32":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer33":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer34":["Do not consider"],"Answer35":["Environmental impact"],"Answer36":["Very important consideration"],"Answer37":["Important consideration"],"Answer38":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer39":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer40":["Do not consider"],"Answer41":["In-flight service"],"Answer42":["Very important consideration"],"Answer43":["Important consideration"],"Answer44":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer45":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer46":["Do not consider"],"Answer47":["Customer support"],"Answer48":["Very important consideration"],"Answer49":["Important consideration"],"Answer50":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer51":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer52":["Do not consider"],"Answer53":["Overcrowding on aircraft/airports"],"Answer54":["Very important consideration"],"Answer55":["Important consideration"],"Answer56":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer57":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer58":["Do not consider"],"Answer59":["Airport safety after COVID-19"],"Answer60":["Very important consideration"],"Answer61":["Important consideration"],"Answer62":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer63":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer64":["Do not consider"],"Answer65":["Refund policy"]}

{k:v for k,v in collections.Counter(d[3:].values).items() if v>1}
```

Obtengo:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-219-2838363412f9> in <module>
      1 d = {"QID":[1177],"Questions":["The travel restrictions of COVID-19 have been lifted and you are looking to book a flight. To what extent are the following factors considerations in your choice of flight?"],"QType":["Likert Scale"],"Answer0":["Very important consideration"],"Answer1":["Important consideration"],"Answer2":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer3":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer4":["Do not consider"],"Answer5":["Discounted flights"],"Answer6":["Very important consideration"],"Answer7":["Important consideration"],"Answer8":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer9":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer10":["Do not consider"],"Answer11":["Baggage policy"],"Answer12":["Very important consideration"],"Answer13":["Important consideration"],"Answer14":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer15":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer16":["Do not consider"],"Answer17":["Price of flights"],"Answer18":["Very important consideration"],"Answer19":["Important consideration"],"Answer20":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer21":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer22":["Do not consider"],"Answer23":["Insurance"],"Answer24":["Very important consideration"],"Answer25":["Important consideration"],"Answer26":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer27":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer28":["Do not consider"],"Answer29":["Airport services"],"Answer30":["Very important consideration"],"Answer31":["Important consideration"],"Answer32":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer33":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer34":["Do not consider"],"Answer35":["Environmental impact"],"Answer36":["Very important consideration"],"Answer37":["Important consideration"],"Answer38":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer39":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer40":["Do not consider"],"Answer41":["In-flight service"],"Answer42":["Very important consideration"],"Answer43":["Important consideration"],"Answer44":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer45":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer46":["Do not consider"],"Answer47":["Customer support"],"Answer48":["Very important consideration"],"Answer49":["Important consideration"],"Answer50":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer51":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer52":["Do not consider"],"Answer53":["Overcrowding on aircraft/airports"],"Answer54":["Very important consideration"],"Answer55":["Important consideration"],"Answer56":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer57":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer58":["Do not consider"],"Answer59":["Airport safety after COVID-19"],"Answer60":["Very important consideration"],"Answer61":["Important consideration"],"Answer62":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer63":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer64":["Do not consider"],"Answer65":["Refund policy"]}
      2 
----> 3 {k:v for k,v in collections.Counter(d[3:].values).items() if v>1}

TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count requiere un iterable, una lista. Lo primero será hacer una lista con los items a contabilizar:

```
a=[x[0] for x in list(d.values())[3:]]
print({k:v for k,v in collections.Counter(a).items() if v>1})
```

produce:

```
{'Not an important consideration': 10, 'Somewhat consider': 11, 'Important consideration': 11, 'Do not consider': 10, 'Very important consideration': 11}
```